# How did you create the documentation page?

Tags: aframe

I am Waseem Ahmed. I really liked your documentation page (https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/#getting-started). Specifically the way all the documents arranged in the left hand side panel and ability to select any topic and move to the next document from footer link. Would you please let me know which documentation portal you are using for your documents? I would like to create similar documentation for my website. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [github repo](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-site) for their website. It's mentioned that they built the website using the [Hexo](https://hexo.io/docs/#What-is-Hexo) framework.

> This site is built using hexo. Site content is written in Markdown (and located in the src/ directory). Pull requests are welcome!

Although, you don't necessarily need to use Hexo. There are plenty of [static site generators](https://jamstack.org/generators/) (SSGs) you can use to generate your documentation.